# How do I set the date and time sync on fedora lxde?

Tags: linux, fedora, date-time, control-panel, lxde

From the following link (https://spins.fedoraproject.org/) I installed the LXDE spin for Fedora 26.

For the life of me, I cannot seem to set the time to sync with a time server so that is it correct for my timezone. I tried doing:

```
sudo dnf install system-config-*
```

I tried `ntpupdate` which is also sometimes why I can't install with DNF and it doesn't exist on my machine.

the `lxpanel` instance for LXDE for digital clock settings, only has the ability to control the text format of the clock and nothing else. I can't even manage to find how to change the time.

Is it so hard just to get a date/time setting applet installed on fedora LXDE? There seems to be tons of solutions applicable to Ubuntu but not Fedora.

I was hoping for a less resource hungry system so I went with LXDE, but if it doesn't even come with the basic stuff then it isn't so much worth it. Are packages famous enough on KDE Plasma Fedora?

Comment: I mean't to post this on unix.se perhaps a mod could move it there ?

Answer (score 1):

Fedora [defaulted](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/ChronyDefaultNTP) the NTP client to `chrony` around Fedora 16. So, no more classical `ntp` unless you install it manually.

Documentation for **chrony** can be found with `man chronyd` for the daemon (client) and `man chronyc` for the users' command line tool.

Config file is: `/etc/chrony.conf`

More information can be found in [the developers documentation].(http://chrony.tuxfamily.org/documentation.html)

In your case, run `chronyc sources` to see whether your client identifies some sources, and `chronyc refresh` to sync with one of the sources. If that fails, check if the daemon is active `systemctl status chronyd`.